# Wordpress Query with Multiple meta_keys not working

Tags: php, wordpress

Ok, so I am querying events made by The Events Calendar, using Advanced Custom Fields.  I have a plugin that converts the serialized data to standard under a new meta_key.  That said, I am able to query events by the meta_key and meta_value individually. i.e

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'tribe_events',
    'meta_key'      => 'display_override',
    'meta_value'    => 'Arkansas Literary Festival'
);
```

and also

```
// args
$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'tribe_events',
    'meta_key'      => 'display_global',
    'meta_value'    => 'Enabled'
);
```

However, I can not get them to work simultaneously, i.e

```
// args
$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'tribe_events',
    'meta_query'    =>  array(
        'relation'  =>  'OR',
        array(
            'key'   =>  'display_override',
            'value' =>  'Arkansas Literary Festival',
            'compare'   => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key'   =>  'display_global',
            'value' =>  'Enabled',
            'compare'   =>  '='
        )
    )
);
```

When I experiment with this, by using 'OR' or 'AND', and 'LIKE' instead of '=', I either get no posts, or I get the master list of unfiltered posts....